# Event after calling setState gives me previous state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to create a search bar for my React.js app.

I have passed `getSearch()` method of app.js to child component navigation to retrieve the input value.

In `getSearch()` method there is `setState({searchTerm:e.target.value})` which is the retrieved value, and then i am calling the `fetchData()` method of app.js right after the `setState()` withing `getSearch()`.

in `fetchData()` method `this.state.searchTerm` is passed as body for `fetch()`, but as I enter something and click enter it gives me the previous value of `this.state.searchTerm` and not latest updated value which user inputs.

What am I doing wrong? I am pasting my app.js for review:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";

import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import Game from "./components/games";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import NotFound from "./components/Notfound";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gameFetched: "false",
      searchTerm: ""
    };
  }
  getSearch = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({
        searchTerm: e.target.value
      });
      this.fetchIGBD()
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchIGBD();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Navigation getSearch={this.getSearch} />
            <div id="main-wrapper" className="d-flex">
              <Sidebar />
              <div id="content">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/" component={Game} exact />
                  <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                  <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }

  fetchIGBD = () => {
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/api-v3.igdb.com/games";
    let data ="fields name,cover,first_release_date,genres.name,platforms.name,total_rating;limit 10;sort popularity;where total_rating > 80;where release_dates.platform = 6;";
    let search = "search '"+this.state.searchTerm+"';";
    if (search !== "") {
      data = data + search
      console.log(data)
    }
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "user-key": "myid"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    this.setState({
      gameFetched: "true"
    });
  };
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following:

```
this.setState({
  searchTerm: e.target.value
 }, () => { 
  this.fetchIGBD()
});
```

`setState` function is async which means it doesn't executes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the state in your `fetchIGBD` method you need to call it in the `callback` parameter of the `setState`. That is required because `setState` is asynchronous.

```
  getSearch = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({
        searchTerm: e.target.value
      }, this.fetchIGBD);
    }
  };
```

or if you need to pass parameters to it

```
  getSearch = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({
        searchTerm: e.target.value
      }, ()=> this.fetchIGBD(params_here));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way of calling `fetchIGBD` is to use callback of `setState` method.It will ensure that you get updated value of `searchTerm`.It will triggered after `setState` complete.

```
   getSearch = e => {
     if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({
        searchTerm: e.target.value
      },function(){
        this.fetchIGBD()
      }
     );
    
  }
};
```